# Using 's in possession

Tags: possessives

Could you explain the difference between these two examples?

1) Mary's and George's children are...
2) Mary and George's children are...

Also,

I have seen in a newspaper a sentence where there was this: "The Trump administration". Why isn't there 's? I thought it should be "The Trump's administration".

Answer (score 4):

In your first question:

> Mary's and George's children

Denotes that you are talking about (Mary's children) **and** (George's children), who *may not be the same children*.

> Mary and George's children

Denotes that you are referring to the children of (Mary and George), as a singular unit.

---

"The Trump Administration" uses a convention in English where a noun can be used to describe another noun, by using the article *the* in "The Trump administration". It would be synonymous with "Trump's Administration", but not "**The** Trump's Administration"